# javascript won't write html

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to write a few `<div>s` with javascript, the problem is: my javascript doesn't. somehow it execute the function 'till the end of it. It just stops the function and goes on with the code.

the jscript code:

```
function Bedrijf(index) { 
    var ind = index;        
    var t = (ind + 1).toString();
    var id = "id" + t;
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    body.innerHTML('<div data-role="page" id="' + id + '">' +
    '<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">' +
    '<div id="text"><span></span></div></div>' +
    '<ul data-role="listview"><li><a href="#home" 
    data-transition="slide">Keer terug</a></li></ul></div>'
    ); 
    var lijst = document.getElementById('lijst');
    lijst.innerHTML('<li><a href="#' + id + 
    '" data-id="' + ind + '" data-transition="slide"> bedrijf' +
        ind + '</a></li>'
    );
}

function Load( )    {
    window.alert("ok");
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Bedrijf(i);
    };
    window.alert("gelukt");
}
```

html code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="lijst">
    <li>
        <a href='#id1' data-id="pierard" data-transition="slide">ijzerwaren Pierard</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href='#id2' data-id="rosa" data-transition="slide">Rosa's sweet corner</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

at the end of the index file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Load( );
    window.alert("all done");
</script>
```

Comment: `body.innerHTML` is not a function and may replace all the body content, you need to append the content to the container, `body.innerHTML += "..."` , same for `lijst.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like hacketo said, `innerHTML` isn't a function. The correct way to use it would be like this:

```
body.innerHTML += '<div data-role="page" id="' + id + '">' +
  '<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">' +
  '<div id="text"><span></span></div></div>' +
  '<ul data-role="listview"><li><a href="#home" 
  data-transition="slide">Keer terug</a></li></ul></div>';
```

And you would want to do the same for wherever else you used `innerHTML`. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Comment: now the only problem is: it still doesn't write them on my html page, it doesn't even give the alerts

Comment: I believe that the problem is that you're using `getElementsByTagName()` to get a reference to the body. You typically don't do that for a single element, because that method returns a collection of elements. Try using `var body = document.body;`. You will actually be referencing the body once you do this.

Answer (score -1):

You shoud write `innerHTML +=`
So you need replace the strings with innerHTML on

```
body.innerHTML += 
lijst.innerHTML +=
```

This is not correct syntaxis - **innerHTML()** 
This is a correct syntaxis - **innerHTML +=**

Comment: now the only problem is: it still doesn't write them on my html page, it doesn't even give the alerts